# Close tcp port with no process

Tags: linux, port, tcp

I ended up in situation with a TCP port in listen mode with no process assigned to it.

Is there a way to close this port without restarting server?

Checking port status:

```
me> netstat -tan | grep 8888
tcp        0      0 :::8888                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Looking for process responsible:

```
me> lsof -i -P | grep 8888
```

*Above command returns nothing*

Comment: service networking restart ?

Comment: Do you have zombie procs open? You seem to know which process opened the port. Maybe you should run `ps -ef` to grep for the process in question, then kill its parent PID.

Answer (score 2):

Try `netstat -ltpn | grep 8888`

Comment: also look at `rpcinfo -p`

Comment: _______ Also not

Comment: As well what do you mean?

Comment: I meant that `netstat` is enough to answer to original question.

Comment: It won't answer the question if the port is opened by the kernel alone. `netstat` has no knowledge of the source of kernel portmap.

Comment: @Jodie C, RPC is remote-proc-call, user-level, actually.

Comment: sunrpc, lockd, nfsd, exportfs are all Linux kernel modules. Try running `netstat -plant` on an NFS server.

Comment: @Jodie C, I have no one, alas. Nevertheless, lockd/nfsd aren't kernel modules. They use kernel level parts.

Comment: they *are* kernel modules and the init scripts for nfs-kernel-server on Debian/Ubuntu simply run `modprobe nfsd`. Have you used NFS before?

Comment: @Jodie C, I've installed NFS utils, and I should admit you were right — I see [nfsd] running in kernel mode, and there're several TCP ports w/o indicated owner in netstat's output. So, you were right, `rpcinfo -p` is worth noting as well. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

run a

```
fuser 8888/tcp
```

That should list pids running on the port.

Comment: Run it, returns no output.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing an impossible scenario.

I believe what the previous posters are missing is the fact that you are trying to map a port to a process which you do not own. Therefore your `lsof` returns nothing since those tools do not have permission view the `/proc` entries that would facilitate that port -> PID mapping. Your `netstat` command is lacking a -p flag as well.  Run those commands as `root` then things will be much clearer.

Comment: I am the owner of the process. Do I need to be the root to find my own process?

Comment: You do not need to be root to see your own processes. You can prove my theory wrong by running `sudo netstat -antp | grep 8888` and posting the output. Then we can stop guessing at what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

netstat does parse /proc/net/[tcp|udp|tcp6|udp6] and then scans the /proc/$pid/-area to find matching processes, while fuser and lsof do "only" travel through the whole /proc/$pid/-area to find which processes are known for which sockets. Ultimately, those two different approaches may end in different results.

If there is no process assigned to the socket, there are two options:

- You're using lsof/fuser and there is no process allocating this socket, 
   but e.g. a kernel module is doing so. You need to find that module.
- you're running netstat as an user who may not access /proc/$pid/fd/.

For example, mounting a share via NFS does result in similar "listening" ports. So those ports will re-appear by mounting a NFS share and will disappear after unmounting the NFS share.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-close-listening-port-in-ubuntu-10-04-a-818605/) page recommends running `sudo lsof -i tcp:8888` if netstat is just a dash for the process name.

In my case it ended up being owned by a [zombie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516398/8337) process, weird, I know.

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:8888
COMMAND       PID USER FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
my-proc-name 38116 root   16u  IPv6 326070554      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
```

Then you can look in a "ps" output for 38116 (in this case) to see the defunct process.

```
ps -ef grep 38116
root     38116     1  0 Apr24 ?        00:06:58 [my-proc-name] <defunct>
```

(my guess is it's some kind of zombie process that hasn't cleaned up yet?).

Another [option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97753/8337):

```
sudo ss -apn | grep 8888
```